# Is it safe to connect +3.3V and -12V to get 15.3V on an ATX PSU?

Tags: dc

I have a [Corsair VS350 Power Supply](https://www.corsair.com/eu/en/Categories/Products/Power-Supply-Units/VS-Series%E2%84%A2-VS350-%E2%80%94-350-Watt-Power-Supply/p/CP-9020052-EU) which has a [24-pin connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_(computer)#Wiring_diagrams). Some pins supply +3.3V and one pin supplies -12V. I don't use this PSU in a computer but for other projects.

I basically need a voltage at about 15V to power a [peltier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling). Since I can't just connect several voltages in series (as far as I understand) I had the idea to just use the +3.3V as input voltage and the -12V as output voltage instead of ground. Does that even make sense and is it save?

Comment: Most likely no issues as long as you stay below the lowest rated current of the two rails. How much current do you need and what are +3.3 and -12 rated for?

Comment: The peltier needs 10A. I'm not sure about the rating, on page 9 in the last column of [this](https://www.corsair.com/corsairmedia/sys_master/productcontent/corsair-psu-spec-table.pdf) document it says something about 0.3A for -12V and 14A for 3.3V but I'm not entirely sure what that means.

Comment: So 0.3 A is your limit then. No go.

Comment: @EVARATE your amperage and your load should have been most definitely  part of the question :) !

Comment: _"I basically need a voltage at about 15V to power a peltier"_ 12V is 'about' 15V. Have you tried running the peltier on 12V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an ATX PSU, the -12V cannot possibly source 10A, so you cannot use the peltier between -12V and +3.3V.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there any other way I can get 15V out of the PSU?

Comment: @EVARATE is there a trimpot inside? Are you ok with some soldering?

Comment: The circuit needs to work with any ATX PSU in the end. Also I'm not sure if I am experienced enough to it apart already :D.

Comment: Adjusting the ATX PSU to 15V means opening it, voiding warranty and mucking around with power electronics that can smoke up in flames if something goes wrong. Better get a ready-made adjustable boost converter module that can take 12V in from the unmodified ATX PSU and set it up to output 15V.

Comment: That’s a no then.